Spring Boot 3 on JBoss WildFly and module exclusion
I am deploying a web application written in Spring Boot 3.2.5 into a fresh WildFly 31.0.1
ℹ️ I know, that running Spring Boot applications on WildFly does not make much sense, but I support various customers with specific tastes.
Since I use Hibernate, I remember that WildFly has its own version and it could cause a problem (other dependencies as well). According to the documentation https://docs.wildfly.org/31/Developer_Guide.html#managing-dependencies I am trying to exclude the module in WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
       <module name="org.hibernate"/>
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>

Even though the path wildfly-31.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/hibernate/main/module.xml exists, I am getting a warning:
WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0274: Excluded dependency org.hibernate via jboss-deployment-structure.xml does not exist.

It confuses me. So the question is: Is exclusion still needed and if yes, how should it be done correctly?

It seems that the module org.hibernate is not turned on by default, but it needs a trigger to be added. But it was not triggered in my case https://docs.wildfly.org/31/Developer_Guide.html#which-are-the-implicit-module-dependencies
